# Extend all Swift Objects

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, swift

Is it possible to extend all existing `Swift` objects as when adding a `category` over `NSObject` in Objective C?

According to this [article](https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2014-07-18-exploring-swift-memory-layout.html), all `Swift` objects inherit from the `SwiftObject` class, but I can't add an extension to it.

Is there any solution to this?

Comment: That SwiftObject business may be an implementation detail, but Swift classes that don't inherit from another class are by default root classes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No. Swift objects do not actually inherit from any root base class. The compiler may insert one as an implementation detail, but the *language* does not have this.

The solution is a function, and usually a generic function, rather than a method. Something that applies to "every kind of object" isn't really encapsulated. There are very few actions that apply to every conceivable thing in the universe. But functions can map absolutely anything to absolutely anything else, so are a better tool here.

---

Just as a note, not *all* objects inherit from `NSObject` either, and it's not a language requirement. But you're correct that the vast majority do. Take a look at `NSProxy` for the top of a non-`NSObject` tree (it implements the `NSObject` protocol, but does not inherit from the `NSObject` class). That's why `id` is not the same thing as `NSObject*`.

---

To your question about associated objects, this is built-in:

```
import Foundation

class Thing { }

let thing = Thing()

var MyKey: Character = "0"

objc_setAssociatedObject(thing, &MyKey, "I'm a value!", objc_AssociationPolicy(OBJC_ASSOCIATION_COPY))

println(objc_getAssociatedObject(thing, &MyKey))
```

Is this what you were trying to create? Note that `objc_setAssociatedObject` is also a function, not a method, in ObjC.

Comment: What I was planning to do was to implement something similar to ObjectiveC's associated_object. Any ideas on how to do that with a generic function?

Comment: You can use associated objects with Swift. Why would you recreate it? (Edited answer with an example) Or do you mean something else?

Comment: @RobNapier: Sometimes people define a category to use associated objects to be able to use them via a normal method API rather than having to use the functions from the runtime.

Comment: Sure; I do that all the time to add things to specific classes, but why would you build that on NSObject?